# Spelling mistake if I comment my own post

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling

The error is, that here is written chnages instead of changes.

[image: chnages instead of changes]

Comment: This seems specific to Meta.SO.

Comment: I totally clicked in your comment box image. Reflex.

Comment: I supposed this will be chnaged in the next update.

Comment: @Werner not quite.  Some comments changes rolled out over the weekend, and we typically test things on meta before releasing it on the rest of the network.  This typo would have been visible on SO at some point.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've fixde the typo.

With you in the next buidl (rev rev 2013.9.30.1041).

Comment: ..... I hate you ....

Comment: @Bart - _hic_ back at yuo!

Comment: I hate^H^Het you.

Comment: Enlightened badge, for tihs?

Comment: @Oded Never make any mistaeks.

Comment: @Oded mayb bein abel 2 spel iss enlitened?

Comment: Okay, now you're just going overbored.

Comment: @Emrakul you mean oervbarod?

Comment: Stahp it! Just stahp it... please